# In CruiseControl.net How can I publish only modified files?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a large web project and I would like to publish only the files that were modified by the last checkin. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You need to be more precise: What do You mean by "modified"? Modified by some task that was executed during the build or files marked as modified by sourcecontrol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article that detailed the process using robocopy. I thought perhaps there was a task in ccnet that did this, but I couldn't find one.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/10/06/asp-net-website-continuous-integration-deployment-using-cruisecontrol-net-subversion-msbuild-and-robocopy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing. Do you use a build script? Your best bet is to let your build script do your publishing, you will have much more control over it.

There is a Modification Writer Task that will create an XML file of the detected modifications in that build. You could then have your build script read that and publish just those files.

There is also a Modification Reader and the doc implies that you can use the read in modifications and publish based on that list:

> ```
>  The ModificationReaderTask can now easily read the modification
> ```
>
> file(s) made by project one, into it's
>   own integration,
>          making it possible that these can be used by the existing
>   tasks/publishers of ccnet for project
>   2

However, it doesn't make it to obvious how you would do this. Perhaps the BuildPublisher will use the Modification Reader info. This might get you started.